# R: lmer coding for a (random) discontinuous time for all subjects with multiple treatments

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have a set of data that came from a psychological experiment where `subjects` were randomly assigned to one of four `treatment` conditions and their wellbeing `w` measured on six different occasions. The exact `day` of measurement on each occasion differs  slightly from subject to subject. The first measurement occasion for all subjects is day zero.

I analyse this with lmer :

```
model.a <- lmer(w ~ day * treatment + (day | subject),
  REML=FALSE,
  data=exper.data)
```

Following a simple visual inspection of the change-trajectories of subjects, I'd now like to include (and examine the effect of including) the possibility that the slope of the line for each subject changes at a point mid-way between measurement occasion 3 and 4.

I'm familiar with modeling the alteration in slope by including an additional time-variable in the `lmer` specification. The approach is described in chapter 6 ('Modeling non-linear change') of the book *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis* by Singer and Willett (2005). Following their advice, for each measurement, for each subject, there is now an additional variable called `latter.day`. For measurements up to measurement 3, the value of `latter.day` is zero; for later measurements, `latter.day` encodes the number of days after day 40 (which is the point at which I'd like to include the possible slope-change).

What I cannot see is how to adjust the `lmer` coding of the examples in the Singer and Willett cases to suit my own problem ... which includes the same point-of-slope-change for all subjects as well as a between-subjects factor (`treatment`). I'd appreciate help on how to write the specification for `lmer`.

Comment: You questions 1, 2 and 4 sound like statistics questions rather than programming questions, and would be better suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).  Certainly question 3 is a programming question, so if you want to keep this on SO consider editing to focus just on that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. As @aosmith notes, much of it is statistically based and should be migrated to Cross Validated. Part of this question could be salvaged as a programming question; but I think it would be better to close it and have a more concise and specific question focused on programming proposed. That is to say, this is really **two** sets of questions. The statistics questions would be better on **CV** and the programming one should be re-worded and posted on **SO**.

Comment: @Alex. I have edited the question very substantially to trim it back to the coding. I hope it now better suits SO.

Comment: Can you please provide some example (eg dummy) data? It appears that you have variables `measurement`, `day`, `w`, `treatment`, `subject`, and `latter.day`; but I'm not exactly sure how it's coded. Perhaps it's just me, but this is making it harder to think about the formula-formulation.

Comment: It's also unclear to me if you wish to specify the random piece as `(day | subject)` or as `(measurement | subject)`. Is the random slope by day or by measurement-occasion? .... In either case, if I'm understanding you correctly, I believe you're attempting to conduct [broken-stick regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression) as a random effect. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, Alex ... broken-stick regression.  I hadn't thought of it like that. The breakpoint will be the same for all subjects but the broken-stick regression is a random effect, with day | subject.

Comment: @Alex Your observation that what I am seeking is essentially a random-effects piecewise regression has proved very useful. Thank you. I have had a chance to search for pages relating to "lmer piecewise OR broken-stick", finding https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-January/223452.html and also  http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer at the heading "Piecewise growth curve".

Comment: so, are you ready to post an answer to your own question yet ... ?